# Does clicking on a link <a href> in symfony make a submit of the form?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

hello I have been reviewing this crud that is generated automatically and there are things that I do not understand. For example, when you click:

```
<a href="{{ path('personas_edit', {'id': persona.id}) }}">edit</a>
```

Do you submit the form? I'm asking because I tried to remove the post method from the route (leaving only the get) and it gave me an error (No route found for "POST / people / 4 / edit": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)). It seems that it passes the id by get (that is, by url) but it does not work when i remove the POST method on the route of the edit function in the controller. This is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Repository\MyClassRepository;
use App\Entity\Tablaform;
use App\Form\Formulario2Type;
/**
 * @Route("/personas")
 */

class ControladorFormularios2Controller extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="personas_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(MyClassRepository $myClassRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('controlador_formularios2/index.html.twig', [
            'personas' => $myClassRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="persona_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $tablaForm = new Tablaform();
        $form = $this->createForm(Formulario2Type::class, $tablaForm);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($tablaForm);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('personas_index');
        }

        return $this->render('controlador_formularios2/new.html.twig', [
            'tablaForm' => $tablaForm,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="personas_delete", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    
    public function delete(Request $request, Tablaform $tablaForm): Response
    {
        //if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$tablaForm->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) 
        {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($tablaForm);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('personas_index');
    }
    
     /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="personas_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Tablaform $tablaForm): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(Formulario2Type::class, $tablaForm);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('personas_index');
        }

        return $this->render('controlador_formularios2/edit.html.twig', [
            'tablaForm' => $tablaForm,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

and this is the view:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Listado{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for persona in personas %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ persona.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ persona.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ persona.edad }}</td>
               <td>
                    {{ include('controlador_formularios2/_delete_form.html.twig') }}
                    <a href="{{ path('personas_edit', {'id': persona.id}) }}">edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">no records found</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
     <a href="{{ path('persona_new') }}">Create new</a>   
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: A link cannot submit a form per se, but could be made to do that through some Javascript. Is there any JS involved in this code?

Comment: no, there's not javascript.

Comment: both methods are required. If i remove the "post" method it returns an error too. And i don't understand why because in the twig view it seems that the parameters are send by url.

Comment: It makes sense for both methods to be present because, judging by the controller, that page has a form. So you need `GET` to open it and `POST` to handle the form submission. But it makes no sense for a link to trigger a `POST` request. Are you certain that is the only thing that's happening? That the form isn't submitted at some point?

Comment: oops, you are right. There is a form inside the edit.html.twig. Now makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: /{id}/edit or /{id}/delete, are not really good ideas as for the path names. Put the parameter in the end /update/{id}. Many benefits, e.g. you can setup the firewall to deny access of non-editor - non admin to the whole /edit and/or /delete path. Then not limiting accepted id format is not ideal either. require them to be \d+